# Element does not define a default property

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm working with JavaFX and trying to use FXML, however I've never had any sort of formal training in it, so I'm kind of stumbling about.

I keep running into this here error:
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.

My aim is to try to initialize a Custom Controller class that runs its own FXML file. The code example given by Oracle therefore looks like this:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"> 
  <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
  <Button text="Click Me" onAction="#doSomething"/>
</fx:root>
```

where the controller and root is set in the Controller method.

I'm trying to adapt this code to my own needs, and I was wondering if someone could explain to me why this error comes up if the fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" is ever changed to something like fx:root type="javafx.scene.Parent" if you want me to, I can post some actual code samples.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of default-property is introduced to short circuit your FXML in reality you'd have to write:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"> 
  <children>
    <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
    <Button text="Click Me" onAction="#doSomething"/>
  </children>
</fx:root>
```

if you now change the container type to Parent and you browse the parent class you'll notice that it does not define a children-property which you implicitly assume - children is introduced by Pane.

You should probably read http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure it answers the question.  Quoting the "[Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)"... A class may define a "default property" using the **@DefaultProperty annotation* defined in the javafx.beans package. If present, the sub-element representing the default property can be omitted from the markup." --  That's _not_ in the FXML.  Also a default property is not really initialisation, which needs to have a controller that implements the Initialize interface, I believe.

Comment: It seems to me it answers the question. The initial VBox example works because VBox has a default property "children", which is implicitly assumed, so the TextField and Button elements can be assumed to be the children of VBox. However, Parent does not have a default property for the FXMLLoader does not know what to do with those two elements.